# conceptual entity type not found c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Realizando una modificación para a través de ef realizar un select para la presentación de los datos en base a un where me encuentro con el sgte error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el método en el cual trato de realizar el select mediante ef para posteriormente presentarlo en un datareader y mostrar en los campos ya que la funcionalidad del método es la siguiente, se envía a buscar el id único para obtener los demás datos que corresponde a ese id en la tabla de tratamiento y que posteriormente se muestren los resultados de la consulta en cada textbox, la ultima parte no se si se encuentra correcto o no.

```
public void Obtener_Tratamiento(int sValue, Label txtCod, TextBox txtCon, TextBox txtVal, TextBox txtPorDsc,
       TextBox txtDscto, TextBox txtTotal)
    {
        try
        {
            using (DIENTES_SANOS_ENTITIES db = new DIENTES_SANOS_ENTITIES())
            {
                var tratamiento = db.TBL_TRATAMIENTO.Where(x => x.TRA_ID == sValue)
                                  .Select(x=> new
                                  {
                                      x.TRA_ID,
                                      x.TRA_CONCEPTO,
                                      x.TRA_VALOR,
                                      x.TRA_DESC,
                                      x.TRA_POR_DESC,
                                      x.TRA_TOTAL
                                   })
                                  .ToList();
                if (db.ToDataReader(tratamiento).Read())
                {
                    txtCod.Text = Convert.ToString(db.ToDataReader(tratamiento)["TRA_ID"]);
                    txtCon.Text = Convert.ToString(db.ToDataReader(tratamiento)["TRA_CONCEPTO"]);
                    txtVal.Text = Convert.ToString(db.ToDataReader(tratamiento)["TRA_VALOR"]);
                    txtPorDsc.Text = Convert.ToString(db.ToDataReader(tratamiento)["TRA_POR_DESC"]);
                    txtDscto.Text = Convert.ToString(db.ToDataReader(tratamiento)["TRA_DESC"]);
                    txtTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(db.ToDataReader(tratamiento)["TRA_TOTAL"]);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _ = MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, "SISROL", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

De antemano agradezco su ayuda y guía.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tú quieres retornar un solo elemento desde una colección debes preferir usar `FirstOrDefault` en lugar del `Where`. FirstOrDefault retornara el primero si lo encuentra (y no seguirá buscando), y si no los encuentra retornará `null`

El `select` que tienes puede que sobre, en general son 2 los motivos para usar select:

*(puede haber otros, pero estos 2 son los más comunes)*

1.- Tu estas tienes unos datos de la base de datos, y quieres que el objeto generado a partir de ellos tenga algunos cambios, como cambios de formato, transformaciones, cálculos matemáticos, etc. Entonces los datos de la base de datos no son 100% iguales a lo que tu quieres. (Este no es tu caso, porque tu estas colocando simplemente las columnas)

2.- Tienes una tabla con muchas columnas, y en la consulta no requieres de todas ellas, solo de un subconjunto. Entonces en favor del performance, te traes solos las columnas necesarias. (Este puede ser tu caso, pero sospecho que no)

Por lo que yo voy a borrar el select, si tú lo necesitas lo pones.

Luego la parte donde usas `ToDataReader` sobra absolutamente

```
public void Obtener_Tratamiento(int sValue, Label txtCod, TextBox txtCon, TextBox txtVal, TextBox txtPorDsc,
       TextBox txtDscto, TextBox txtTotal)
    {
        try
        {
            using (DIENTES_SANOS_ENTITIES db = new DIENTES_SANOS_ENTITIES())
            {
                var tratamiento = db.TBL_TRATAMIENTO.FirstOrDefault(x => x.TRA_ID == sValue);
                if (tratamiento!=null)
                {
                    txtCod.Text = tratamiento.TRA_ID.ToString();
                    txtCon.Text = tratamiento.TRA_CONCEPTO; //si es string no necesitas poner ToString
                    txtVal.Text = tratamiento.TRA_VALOR.ToString();
                    txtPorDsc.Text = tratamiento.TRA_POR_DESC.ToString();
                    txtDscto.Text = tratamiento.TRA_DESC.ToString();
                    txtTotal.Text = tratamiento.TRA_TOTAL.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _ = MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, "SISROL", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @yussef un abrazo campeón.!